# Why is Twig not outputting this correctly?

Tags: 8, theming

I have

```
function hook_theme_preprocess(array &$variables, $hook) {
    $variables['bla'] = ' AA <strong> BB </strong> CC ';
}
```

In my template I have:

```
{{ bla }}
```

The problem is, in some cases the  html is stripped. Even if I do this:

```
{{ bla | raw }}
```

This works fine on all pages where this template is used, except on the home page. On the home page, for some bizarre reason, it strips the HTML.

Any idea as to why there would be different behaviour depending on which page I am on?

Comment: So are you saying that when you highlight it, right mouse click and inspect element, all you see is `AA BB CC` ? The `<strong>` tags are gone?

Comment: Yes, but I now redid the whole thing using blocks, so I'll probably never know what caused it.

Comment: I just did exactly what you did and the tags were being printed correctly doing `{{ bla|raw }}`. Since you now choose to use blocks anyway I'd vote for this question being closed as "can no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unsafe to use the `|raw` filter. Put HTML markup in a `#markup` element instead:

```
$variables['foo'] = [
  '#markup' => ' AA <strong> BB </strong> CC ',
];
```

Then outputting this variable in Twig should work:

```
{{ foo }}
```